# how to change Meta Title,Meta Keywords,Meta Description dynamically in AngularJs 1.x?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

I am planning to change meta Title,Meta keywords and Meta description dynamically using AngularJS 1.x to reflect in Facebook,Twitter,Google Plus and LinkedIn.

Is there any way to change dynamically? I am using REST Api calls.

Thanks,
-Venkat

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [this](https://github.com/jvandemo/angular-update-meta) library which is suggested by Tristan also. It works perfectly fine. and compatible with dynamic expressions also.

For updating meta-tags you can simply use the following markup in your view(s):

```
<update-title title="A new title"></update-title>
<update-meta charset="ISO-8859-1"></update-meta>
<update-meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="es"></update-meta>
<update-meta name="description" content="A page specific description"></update-meta>
<update-meta property="og:title" content="Minions"></update-meta>
<update-meta itemprop="description" content="A page specific itemprop description"></update-meta>
```

You can simply install it using this command:

```
bower install angular-update-meta
```

Hope it will help someone.

Comment: for angular 1.x versions?

Comment: ohh, can u help me a bit?, how can i just import the 'file.js' that make the module import works, i dont just np, :S thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular-update-meta , it will help you to update meta tags dynamically.

https://github.com/jvandemo/angular-update-meta

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-bind` to dynamically create the content of any tag.

For example:

```
<title ng-bind="pageTitle()"></title>
```

And then in your controller:

```
$scope.pageTitle = function () {
    return 'the page title you want to add dynamically';
};
```

Google now renders javascript so the dynamic page title, and meta tags, will be indexed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem so I've created a library just for this. You can view it [over here](https://github.com/cozmy/angular-simple-seo).

You can use it in two ways:

1. For each state you've defined using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) you can attach the following custom data: `simpleSeoTitle`, `simpleSeoDescription`, `simpleSeoKeywords`. These 3, whenever the state is active, will change the page's title, description, or keywords.
2. It also exposes a service called `simpleSeoService`. This service has 3 properties, `title,`description`, and`keywords`. These 3 are defined as [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set). These are useful when you have dynamic properties you want to attach.